# How to make many edits to files, without writing to the harddrive very often, in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash

I often need to make many edits to text files. The files are typically 20 MB in size and require ~500,000 individual edits, all which must be made in a very specific order. Here is a simple example of a script I might need to use:

```
while read -r line
do
    ...
    (20-100 lines of BASH commands preparing $a and $b)
    ...
    sed -i "s/$a/$b/g" ./editfile.txt
    ...
done < ./readfile.txt
```

As many other lines of code appear before and after the `sed` script, it seems the only option for editing the file is `sed` with the `-i` option. Many have warned me against using `sed -i`, as that makes too many writes to the file. Recently, I had to replace two computers, as the hard drives stopped working after running the scripts. I need to find a solution that does not damage my computer's hardware.

Is there some way to send files somewhere else, such as storing the whole file into a BASH variable, or into RAM, where I `sed`, `grep`, and `awk`, can make the edits without making millions of writes to the hard drive?

Comment: have you thought about setting up a RAM drive?

Comment: It's not clear from the question why the edits need to be made in a specific order, or why the file needs to be written after every single edit. Do the bash commands within the loop depend on the contents of each line? You might want to consider loading the file to be edited into memory using, for example, a Perl script and performing the substitutions from there.

Comment: See [Memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)

Comment: The order of edits is often important, e.g. if `sed 's/1100/AAAA/g'`, `sed 's/100/CCC/g'`, and `sed 's/00/EE/g'` are all in different orders against a file containing many numbers and no segments, the output will be different.

Comment: Prior to the `sed` script are many commands, e.g. some check data from `$line`, then retrieve related information from other files, making various changes to the data, before giving some final information to `sed` to make the actual edit. I did not post specifics as I have many different scripts, each different, but all requiring `sed -i` in a while loop.

Comment: Switching to `perl` would not be a good choice as it seems poorly suited to handling the files which contain texts in various languages and many symbols.

Comment: Expanding on @TomFenech 's suggestion, what if you kind of store the changes to be done and then loop through them? It might be faster to do `sed -e 'command1' -e 'command2' file` than `sed 'command1' file` and then `sed 'command2' file`, etc.

Comment: Can `sed` be given 500,000 commands all on one line like that?

Comment: I don't grok the claim that Perl is unsuited for handling non-English or non-ASCII content. Could you clarify? (Personally, I hate the language -- but it has enough _real_ design warts and misfeatures to not have any need to make up imaginary ones).

Comment: (If you wanted to use a language built with Unicode baked in all the way down, there's also Python 3... though if native Unicode were a requirement, sed wouldn't be working for you either).

Comment: Are all the edits `sed` invocations? If so, put them all in one file and invoke `sed` once per file as `sed -f sed_command_list.txt  ...`. Put each individual command (typically `s/foo/bar/` or some such) on it's own line within the script file...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `sed -i` once per transform. A far better approach -- leaving you with more control -- is to construct a pipeline (if you can't use a single `sed` with multiple `-e` arguments to perform multiple operations within a single instance), and redirect to or from disk at only the beginning and end.

This can even be done recursively, if you use a FD other than stdin for reading from your file:

```
editstep() {
  read -u 3 -r line     # read from readfile into REPLY
  if [[ $REPLY ]]; then # we read something new from readfile
    sed ... | editstep  # perform the edits, then a recursive call!
  else
    cat
  fi
}

editstep <editfile.txt >editfile.txt.new 3<readfile.txt
```

Better than that, though, is to consolidate to a single `sed` instance.

```
sed_args=( )
while read -r line; do
  sed_args+=( -e "s/in/out/" )
done <readfile.txt
sed -i "${sed_args[@]}" editfile.txt
```

...or, for edit lists too long to pass in on the command line:

```
sed_args=( )
while read -r line; do
  sed_args+=( "s/in/out/" )
done <readfile.txt
sed -i -f <(printf '%s\n' "${sed_args[@]}") editfile.txt
```

(Please don't read the above as an endorsement of `sed -i`, which is a non-POSIX extension and has its own set of problems; the POSIX-specified editor intended for in-place rather than streaming operations is `ex`, not `sed`).

---

Even better? Don't use `sed` at all, but keep all the operations inline in native bash.

Consider the following:

```
content=$(<editfile.txt)
while IFS= read -r; do
  # put your own logic here to set `in` and `out`
  content=${content//$in/$out}
done <readfile.txt
printf '%s\n' "$content" >editfile.new
```

One important caveat: This approach treats `in` as a literal string, not a regular expression. Depending on the edits you're actually making, this may actually *improve* correctness over the original code... but in any event, it's worth being aware of.

Another caveat: Reading the file's contents into a bash string is not necessarily a lossless operation; expect content to be truncated at the first NUL byte (if any exist), and a trailing newline to be added at the end of the file if none existed before.

Comment: @twalberg, indeed. I thought of that after finishing the answer, but decided I was too lazy to edit it in. Amending now -- it really _is_ a better approach than most of those given here.

Comment: So, in the third example code, it is creating a long list of things for `sed` to do, then after the while loop is finished, `sed` does all of those edits at once? Does `sed` make fewer writes to the hard drive when this is done? Is there any maximum to how much the `sed` can hold?

Comment: Each `sed` instance will write the whole file from start to finish.  The fewer `sed` instances you spawn, the less you will exercise the hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

simple ...

instead of trying too many threads, you can simple copy all your files and dirs to **/dev/shm**
This is representation of ram drive. When you are done editing, copy all back to the original destination. Do not forget to run **sync** after you are done :-)

Comment: Why is this down voted? Does this solution not work?

Comment: If you cannot reduce the number of writes it helps ameliorate the symptoms, but it doesn't really attempt to solve your problem.  (I'm not the downvoter, but I considered upvoting to compensate, and decided not to.)